# rich columns with sortBy example

Tags: richfaces, dynamic-columns

Can some one please provide an example of rich:columns backing bean and tag implementation along with sortBy Feature.

Answer (score 0):

This may help: http://mkblog.exadel.com/2008/11/richfaces-sorting-and-filtering-complete-edition/